# Getting index of selected rows in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, features, select, index

Suppose I make a selection on some layer and I want to apply some function on only those records.

I know there's a box you can check in the Field Calculator for this, but is there a function/expression I could use alternatively?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator), under the `Record and Attributes` header, you've got the [`is_selected()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#is-selected) function which returns True if the feature is selected.